# WooCommerce Product image is not displaying. display: none !important;

Tags: css, wordpress, image, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce, with the theme Seos Video. I have the plugins, Page Builder by SiteOrigin, SiteOrigin CSS, SiteOrigin Widgets Bundle, WooCommerce, WooCommerce Display Products by Tags, and WooCommerce Products Carousel all in one installed.

I have loaded in three products so far, they all load and display correctly in a carousel sidebar, in the product thumbnails, and searches. When a product is selected and the main product page loads, it will not always display the image. In two of the products when I checked the css for that section it shows the image as loaded, but has

> style="display:none !important"

This is directly added in at some point during the load cycle and I have been unable to track down the main culprit. The second product I loaded is working as intended.

I have tried with several themes, and the issue persists regardless of which theme I pick. I am certain that there is an underlying issue that is causing it, as the page is still laid out as if the image were there. It registers and loads the image on each page, but then the display takes over and it cannot be removed, even manually with the debugger manually changing the line. It reverts after the line is disabled or changed.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve my issue using the plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

After the regeneration everything worked as intended.